# Comparing counts of category in same column

Tags: sql

Anyone know how to solve this?

I kept getting an error on this

[image]

Comment: Could you use text to describe problem?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a part of `select distinct`. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select distinct place` to make code clearer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the data by `place`, and then use a a `having` clause to filter groups that have more recommended opinions that not recommended options.

You could express the condition with a conditional sum, like so:

```
select place
from opinions
group by place
having 
    sum(case opinion 
        when 'recommended'     then 1 
        when 'not recommended' then -1 
    end) > 0
order by place
```